# How to detect ENTER key on button

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using this code. panelButtons[] is an array of buttons.

```
        for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
        {
            int temp = i;
            panelButtons[temp].KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(checkKeyPress);
        }
    }
    private void checkKeyPress(object a, KeyPressEventArgs b)
    {
        if(b.KeyChar==(char)Keys.Enter || b.KeyChar==(char)Keys.Return)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Enter");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that, it is NOT detecting enter key. I have searched a lot on net, but all I get is how to detect ENTER key on textbox. This method, and many other similar to this(like KeyDown idea) are not working.

Comment: I Does it detect any key properly?

Comment: Try .Click and see if it triggers when the enter key is pressed then.

Comment: the problem is the same as in textboxes. The button itself handles the "enter"-key to be pushed. so you have to avoid this behaviour

Comment: What i want is to prevent ENTER or SPACEBAR to fire panelButtons[temp] event, so that the it can be only fired when clicked by mouse.

And yeah..other buttons do work properly. Only ENTER does not.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on your method and checking that the code is being called? That is: is the event handler incorrect, or is it not even being wired up? You don't include where your initial `for` loop is called from, for example - is it possible that it's not being called at all?

Comment: Your assumption that the button's KeyPress event will fire when you press the Enter key is just wrong.  It is a navigation key, like Tab and the cursor keys.  Override the form's ProcessCmdKey() method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the PreviewKeyDown-Event of that Button and set the PreviewKeyDownEventArgs.IsInputKey to True

```
Private Sub Button1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles Button1.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then e.IsInputKey = True
End Sub
```

Comment: i updated my answer: first i said set to false, correct is to set the property to true